# Get Key / Value of JSON object with Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json

I see many questions and answers about what I'm trying to do but after reading the answers I'm not able to get the key and value out of this json.

Here is the json being returned:

```
      {
"@odata.context": "https://con813-crm612cf723bbf35af6devaos.cloudax.dynamics.com/data/$metadata#Customers(CustomerAccount,Name)",
"value": [
    {
        "@odata.etag": "W/\"JzAsMjI1NjU0MjE1NTg7MCwwOzAsNTYzNzE0NTMyODswLDU2MzcxNDQ1NzY7MCwyMjU2NTQyNTY5MzswLDIyNTY1NDI3MjM2OzAsMDswLDIyNTY1NDI3MjM2OzAsMjI1NjU0MjcyMzY7MCwwJw==\"",
        "CustomerAccount": "DE-001",
        "Name": "Contoso Europe"
    },
    {
        "@odata.etag": "W/\"JzAsMjI1NjU0MjE1NTk7MCwwOzAsMzU2MzcxNDkxMTI7MCw1NjM3MTQ0NTc3OzAsMjI1NjU0MjU2OTQ7MCwyMjU2NTQyNzIzODswLDA7MCwyMjU2NTQyNzIzODswLDIyNTY1NDI3MjM4OzAsMCc=\"",
        "CustomerAccount": "US-001",
        "Name": "Contoso Retail San Diego"
    },
    {
        "@odata.etag": "W/\"JzAsMjI1NjU0MjE1NjA7MCwwOzAsMzU2MzcxNDkxMTM7MCw1NjM3MTQ0NTc4OzAsMjI1NjU0MjU2OTU7MCwyMjU2NTQyNzI0MDswLDA7MCwyMjU2NTQyNzI0MDswLDIyNTY1NDI3MjQwOzAsMCc=\"",
        "CustomerAccount": "US-002",
        "Name": "Contoso Retail Los Angeles"
    }
]
```

}

I need to get the names of the keys, which is "CustomerAccount" and "Name" in this example, and then their values. I can't figure out to just return those values.

```
        JObject parsedJson = JObject.Parse(_json);

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (JProperty property in parsedJson.Properties())
        {
            builder.Append((string.Format("Name: [{0}], Value: [{1}].", property.Name, property.Value)));
        }
```

Hoping to add more clarity; In this example I would like to write out the key/values after "@odata.etag" which the keys are "CustomerAccount" and "Name" and their values are after the colon. The keys/values are dynamic so I need to loop through writing out whatever the key names and values are after each "@odata.etag" value.

Comment: "_I can't figure out to just return those values_" What exactly do you want to return and how? Do you just want to return the string built in the StringBuilder? Is building the string itself the problem? Or is the problem not with building the string itself, but rather with how to return the built string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` and pass the type of object you want to parse. there was a missing closing curly brace at the end. I hope I understood what you want to do correctly, if not plz leave a comment

```
    class Value
    {
        public string CustomerAccount { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }

    class Customer
    {
        public List<Value> Value { get; set; }

    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

          var obj =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer>(@"     {
            '@odata.context': 'https://con813-crm612cf723bbf35af6devaos.cloudax.dynamics.com/data/$metadata#Customers(CustomerAccount,Name)',
            'value': [
            {
                '@odata.etag': 'W/\'JzAsMjI1NjU0MjE1NTg7MCwwOzAsNTYzNzE0NTMyODswLDU2MzcxNDQ1NzY7MCwyMjU2NTQyNTY5MzswLDIyNTY1NDI3MjM2OzAsMDswLDIyNTY1NDI3MjM2OzAsMjI1NjU0MjcyMzY7MCwwJw==\'',
                'CustomerAccount': 'DE-001',
                'Name': 'Contoso Europe'
            },
            {
                '@odata.etag': 'W/\'JzAsMjI1NjU0MjE1NTk7MCwwOzAsMzU2MzcxNDkxMTI7MCw1NjM3MTQ0NTc3OzAsMjI1NjU0MjU2OTQ7MCwyMjU2NTQyNzIzODswLDA7MCwyMjU2NTQyNzIzODswLDIyNTY1NDI3MjM4OzAsMCc=\'',
                'CustomerAccount': 'US-001',
                'Name': 'Contoso Retail San Diego'
            },
            {
                '@odata.etag': 'W/\'JzAsMjI1NjU0MjE1NjA7MCwwOzAsMzU2MzcxNDkxMTM7MCw1NjM3MTQ0NTc4OzAsMjI1NjU0MjU2OTU7MCwyMjU2NTQyNzI0MDswLDA7MCwyMjU2NTQyNzI0MDswLDIyNTY1NDI3MjQwOzAsMCc=\'',
                'CustomerAccount': 'US-002',
                'Name': 'Contoso Retail Los Angeles'
            }
            ]
            }");

            foreach (var value in obj.Value)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Name: 'Name' Value: {value.Name}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Name: 'CustomerAccount' Value: {value.CustomerAccount}");
            }

        }
    }
```

If you don't know the keys (properties are dynamic) of the object, you could use the following code snippet but it needs a change in the class declaration.

```
class Customer
{
    //this is list of value objects (value is a dictionary) 
    public List<Dictionary<String,String>> Value { get; set; }

}
```

And here's how to deserialize and loop through the array of values

```
   var obj =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer>(myString);

   foreach (var value in obj.Value)
   {
         foreach (var key in value)
         {
             if (key.Key == "@odata.etag")
                 continue;
             Console.WriteLine("Name: [{0}], Value: [{1}]",key.Key, key.Value);
         }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll never know the key name so I need to write out it's key/value pair. In this example it's CustomerAccount and Name but it could be anything. I need to write out whatever comes after "@odata.etag" which could be unlimited rows and unlimited key/values.

Comment: @Darin, you need to clearly specify what in the Json constitutes a key, what constitutes a value and (unless blatantly obvious in the JSOn, which it currently is not) how precisely is a value being associated with a key. You needing to explain your problem here in response to an answer is a rather big sign telling you that your question lacks clarity and/or information needed to fully comprehend your problem/question.

Comment: @Darin chk the last section of my updated answer, plz don't forget to rate my answer ) thanks